# Angular Highcharts - Dynamically resize series height when selected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, height

I'd like to dynamically resize the chart yAxis series height when the other series are deselected.

I've currently got each series set to 33% height each. From the dropdown, when one series is selected (for example RMS), I want it to become 100% height. When 2 (Peak & RMS) are selected, 50% height each. When 3 selected (RMS, Peak & Duration) 33% height each.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr3k7.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMZT9.png <-- Problem
With 100% height https://i.stack.imgur.com/spkQM.png <-- Desired Result

```
yAxis: [
  {
    height: "33%",
    id: "rms",
    resize: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  {
    top: "33%",
    height: "33%",
    id: "peak",
    resize: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  {
    top: "66%",
    height: "33%",
    id: "duration"
  }
],
```

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE] please?

Comment: is redrawing an option?  than it would not be a smooth transition but you could return a new chart with the adjusted parameters.

Comment: When I add 100% height to each series, it seems to work well but the problem I have then is that they overlap and top:value is ignored. https://i.imgur.com/j6kfq6F.png

Comment: You could try to use `series.events.legendItemClick`, and inside of that events function, check how many series has `visible` flag set to `true`, then just iterate on all axes and adjust the height. Would be much easier to prepare the example if you would provide us with minimal example.